# You're both of us' child / You're both of our child / You're both of ours child - Why are these all ungrammatical?

Tags: determiners, saxon-genitive, possessive-pronouns

There was an interesting question on our  sister site [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/):

- [Is “Both of our child” valid?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77691/is-both-of-our-child-valid)

Suppose a kid asks their mother "*Am I your child or Dad's child?*": Why are the alternatives in the title grammatically wrong?

- *You're both of us' child
- *You're both of our child
- *You're both of ours child

After all we can have coordinated plurals as the possessors:

- You're [Mary and John]'s child

You can obviously have:

- You're [the McDonald]'s child

You can have:

- You're [the couple who robbed them]'s child

Yes, I know: it's not elegant - but it's grammatical nonetheless.

What reasons are there for the examples in the title being ungrammatical?

This question isn't about how to rephrase the kid's answer. It's about why the examples are ungrammatical.

Comment: "You are both of us' child" or "You are both of us's child" would appear not to be *ungrammatical,* although it's certainly awkward and would normally be rephrased.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That's interesting. It feels very wonky to me, not just awkward. I wonder what other people will think ... ?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Out of interest, which one's best for you: "You're both of them's child" or "Your both of their's child"? It's a bit weird because I kind of agree that "us'(s)" is the least bad. But it doesn't follow through for me for the other pronouns. Also without the following noun, "child", I feel that "You're both of ours" is ok, whereas "You're both of us'(s)" is far wonkier.

Comment: Good question. But what if we say " you are both of our child's". Is it ungrammatical?

Comment: @haha Good question too! I don't think it's ungrammatical, but it seems to me that the meaning's different. It would imply that our child possessed something: "Both of our child's  friends are coming to the party" for example. Here the *both* is there because there are two friends, not because there are two of us, I think. :)

Comment: @Araucaria It's not possible. "You're our child" would seem a reasonable alternative. The "our" bit (i.e. us, each of your parents) would be clear in the conversation by deixis.

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, of course :)

Comment: @BillJ Thanks, but I know it's not possible! I want to know why! :-) Sometimes with my questions I already have an idea about why. I don't have the foggiest in this case though.

Answer (score 3):

As you note, you can have co-ordinated plurals:

- You're [Mary and John]'s child
- You're [the McDonalds'] child
- You're [the couple who robbed them]'s child

All use a phrase and the Saxon genitive. The last one is grammatical but awkward enough to rephrase as

- You're the child of the couple who robbed them

This would suggest that **any similar structure is grammatical:**

- You're [both of us]'s child

And again, that's awkward enough to rephrase:

- You're the child of both of us.

The noun phrase is not changed whichever genitive form is used:

- You're Mary and John's child :: You're the child of Mary and John
- You're both of us's child :: You're the child of both of us
- *You're both of our child :: *You're the child of both of our

---

The forms with *our* are ungrammatical because although *we's* or *us's* becomes *our,* this doesn't happen with the noun phrase *both of us:* the possessive has to apply **to the whole phrase,** not simply the last word. In order to apply it to the whole phrase, it's necessary to use the Saxon genitive just as with *the couple who robbed them* — that doesn't become *their.*

Using *our* actually divorces that possessive from *both,* so that *both* refers to the **following** noun (so *child* is obviously wrong, because *both* requires a plural).

- *Both of our child
- Both of our children

Because of the ungrammatical nature of the example, it's necessary to change it slightly to produce something which is grammatical, demonstrating that *both* refers to *children*:

- You're both of our children, and we never had any more.

Comment: Edited: Nice points, nicely presented. Am pondering ... At the moment, my thoughts are that *them* is necessarily accusative because it's an Object in *the couple who robbed them*, but *us/ours* isn't necessarily accusative. It could be genitive. The phrases *both of us* and *both of ours* are equally well formed. I still can't tell whether *both of us('s)* is grammatical in my variety of English - though I'm not saying it isn't in any others. Hmmm ...

Comment: "Both of us" and "Both of ours" are different from each other, and different again from "Both of us's". I hold [obv!] that the last is strictly grammatical, but sufficiently awkward to have been eradicated. Since it is eradicated, it's even more awkward, a vicious or virtuous circle, depending on your point of view.

Comment: +1 Ok, I think you might have something in your answer, but I can't tell. My first problem is that *both of ours* seems good and I can't see why *both of us's chils* should use an accusative extrapolating from that. My other problem is that it still seems ungrammatical to me (as in it kicks my natural ear funny bone). But I'm willing to accept that it isn't for you and maybe there's a N/S divide going on, or maybe it's just my idiolect. I still want to know why it's wonky in my variety of English - but I think you have a point, especially about it cliticising on a whole NP, not a noun.

Comment: I don't know about N/S; maybe E/W. I'll have a think about the accusative point with a view to updating the answer, but it's getting late here.

Comment: Actually, I think the *both* is the problem. Consider "You're both of them's child," which I believe to be strictly grammatical, but **so** awkward due to *them's* and its uneducated overtones for "They are" that it has to be changed. That doesn't seem to be the case for "the couple who robbed them". Coo. Interesting.

Comment: @AndrewLeach In what other circumstances would you use *them's* when there is a perfectly good possessive pronoun in *their*?  I can't think of any instance where one would form a possessive pronoun by adding 'apostrophe s', other than *its* and in that case we elide the apostrophe. It is always awkward forming a possessive from a phrase- *the man who trod on my foot's umbrella* - and far simpler to use *of* - *the child of both of us*.

Comment: “You’re both of our children” seems to imply that you’re talking to two children that are both offspring of “our children” - you’re grandchildren in other words.

Comment: I'm afraid we're pretty much all children of MacDonalds, at this point.

Comment: @Araucaria The accusative pronoun is an issue, but I'm not sure how to codify it. It has something to do with the nominative noun phrase which is cliticised to form a genitive being the same as the genitive noun phrase with *of,* as in my pairs in the first half of the answer. It has something to do with the *of* in *both of,* possibly because the *of* is used in the Romance genitive (if that's what it's called) and it creates an ambiguity.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, re "This would suggest that **any similar structure is grammatical**:

You're [both of us]'s child" -- Are you aware of whether this definition of "grammatical" you're invoking is common among some subset of linguists, teachers, speakers, etc., and you're using this term based on that? If not, what *is* the basis of how you define "grammatical"?